# Swift how to pause audio

Tags: ios, swift

So I am creating a simple radio station app. I have coded the following and got the play / pause button switching text. I just can't work out how to access the player in the button when the func is inside ViewDidLoad. I am sure I need to set global variables?

```swift
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://stream.radiomedia.com.au:8003/stream") else {
        return
    }

    // Create a new AVPlayer and associate it with the player view
    let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
    player.allowsExternalPlayback = true
    player.usesExternalPlaybackWhileExternalScreenIsActive = true

    // Create a new AVPlayerViewController and pass it a reference to the player.
    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.contentOverlayView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    playerViewController.view.frame = CGRect (x:100, y:100, width:200, height:200)
    playerViewController.player = player

    self.addChild(playerViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(playerViewController.view)
    playerViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
    playerViewController.player = player
    player.play()
}

@IBAction func playVideo(_ sender: Any) {
    if(playButton == false){
        playButton = true;
        (sender as! UIButton).setTitle("Pause", for: [])
        player.pause() // does not work
    }else
    {
        playButton = false;
        (sender as! UIButton).setTitle("Play", for: [])
        player.play() // does not work 
    }
}
```

Comment: first radio can't be pause!!.. its stop

Comment: well it is pausing in the test environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class YourVC: UIViewController {
var player = AVPlayer()
}
```

just declare the player inside your class so that other functions can access it.

and in your viewDidApper(), change:

```
let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
```

to

```
self.player = AVPlayer(url: url)
```

then you can call `player.pause()` and `player.play()` from anywhere inside your Class.

Answer (score 1):

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class AudioPlayerVC: UIViewController {

var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("wakeUp", ofType: ".mp3"))
    var error:NSError?
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound, error: &error)
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer.play()
}
@IBAction func onPressPlayPaush(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if(sender == false){
        sender = true
        audioPlayer.pause() 
    }else
    {
        sender = false
        audioPlayer.play() 
    }
}
```